# Webstorm with Java 1.8, Font Weight Changed

Tags: fonts, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm running Webstorm on OSX, and have recently updated to Java 1.8. After updating my font weights have gotten thinner. It is very subtle but there is a definite difference.

Before updating:

[image]

After updating:

[image]

I know other folks that have updated and not experience this (by comparing my fonts to theirs).

Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to change it?

Comment: Please try downloading installation with bundled JDK (v10 [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/) and v11 EAP builds [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP)). Any better (especially v11)?

Comment: I have noticed this too! It put me right off v11 and I went back to v10. A shame really considering v11 has better TypeScript support. Would be great to find out how to get the normal rendering back.

Comment: @jamcoupe check my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Under "Appearance & Behavior > Appearance", change these:

[image]

To these:

[image]

And your fonts will be fat and ugly again. (/s)